# How to terminate current colab session from notebook cell

Tags: python, bash, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to be a good citizen and make sure my notebook session is terminated immediately after running even if I'm not sitting at my machine.

Is there any code I can run in a notebook cell to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm trying to be a good citizen too =)

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Some say it's still running

Comment: @Maximus see answer below

Comment: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2568

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a way to do this correctly now:

```
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```

Answer (score 6):

A rather ugly but efficient solution might be

```
!kill $(ps aux | awk '{print $2}')
```

`ps aux` will give you a list of any process running in the machine, `awk '{print $2}'` will extract the PID of every process currently running and finally `kill` will stop them, sending a SIGTERM signal.

This will give you a message "Runtime disconnected" and the session will be closed, you can see it worked under "Runtime" > "Manage sessions".

You can see the available system aliases [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/basic_features_overview.ipynb)

Comment: The session is still there if you reload the page.

Comment: The session will be restarted after a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

```
!pkill --oldest
```

!pkill is used to kill the program and --oldest is used to kill the oldest program

Answer (score -1):

This might work give it a try.

```
!kill -9 -1
```

Comment: I've tried, but this just restarts the notebook but doesn't terminate.