# Terminate Colab session completely from notebook cell

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to completely kill the session of my Colab after a particular cell is run.

I have tried the solution in the following thread. Although it disconnects the session, the session is reconnected in a few seconds.

[How to terminate current colab session from notebook cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331439/how-to-terminate-current-colab-session-from-notebook-cell)

I want the session to only reconnect when a cell is run by the user or the user presses the reconnect button.